# Remove white spots from luxury vinyl plank flooring

Tags: floor, cleaning, vinyl-flooring

I just moved into an apartment where the floor needs some additional cleaning. The following are two pictures I took (click to enlarge):

[image]
[image]

The floor is vinyl wood (Luxury Vinyl Plank Flooring). I tried to use a Bona hardwood floor mop, but it didn't make any difference. Does anyone know how to do a deep clean for the floor in this situation ?

Comment: Looks like paint spatter.  What do they feel like, hard bumps on the floor?  Removing them without damage to the floor usually requires knowing what they are.

Comment: not paint .. I think its more like dust .. if I take a wet paper towel and scrub them for 5 minutes.. they start to come off .. but I can't do that for whole apartment .. it will take too long

Comment: That sounds like paint to me I would try something like goof off,  but put some in a hidden area to make sure it won’t damage the surface.

Comment: a steam cleaner should blast those right off without hurting the floor. You can also try some solvents to see if any melt them, my favorites are isopropyl alcohol, naptha (lighter fluid), WD40, acetone, and gasoline.

Comment: Just make sure you kick your smoking habit before using any of @dandavis' recommended solutions as they're all rather flammable...